# How should I check if an expiry date has expired?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For example, I want `current_user.subscribed` to be changed to `false` if `current_user.expiry_date` is of a date before `Date.today`.

I don't actually know to implement this. Which controller or action should I link this to (if I should at all?). Is there a way to have this automatically happen?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
subscribed = Date.today < current_user.expiry_date
```

It will return false if user date is expiry.

Answer (score 0):

A good place to implement this would be in the method that logs in the user. You can check the `expiry_date` against `Date.today`

```
current_user.subscribed = false if Date.today > current_user.expiry_date
```

Comment: I use tokens to remember the user automatically unless they click log out. Will this be a problem?

Comment: I don't think so, because you are just modifying the value in one of the columns in the Users table. It shouldn't be affected by the token.